# смысл функции line.split( )[ ][ ]

Tags: python

Есть функция в питон

```
line.split()[][]
```

Что писать и смысл этих параметров в `line.split(?)[?][?]`

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

Comment: там ничего не сказано про то что в скобках [?][?], внутри  split, что нашла инфу

Comment: можете привести [в воспросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/936285/edit) воспроизводимый пример кода, который вызывает у вас затруднения?

Comment: Это всего лишь обращение к элементам списка

Comment: Скобки [][] к функции не относятся , они относятся к ее результату.

Answer (score 6):

[string.split()](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) - возвращает список/массив строк:

```
In [98]: s = "abc def ghi"

In [99]: s.split()
Out[99]: ['abc', 'def', 'ghi']
```

оператор `[]` - позволяет обращаться к элементам списка:

```
In [100]: s.split()[0]
Out[100]: 'abc'
```

строку в Python (в данном случае строку `abc`) можно использовать как список одиночных символов и обращаться к элементам строки при помощи того же оператора `[]`:

```
In [101]: s.split()[0][2]
Out[101]: 'c'
```